# pika acknowledge message after basic_get

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a python code which consumes messages from RMQ one at a time

```
message_count = queue_state.method.message_count
    if not queue_empty:
        message_cursor = 1
        while message_cursor <= message_count:
            method, properties, body = channel.basic_get(queue=QueueName, auto_ack=True)
            callback(channel, method, properties, body)
            message_cursor += 1
```

I did a lot of parsing of received messages in the callback, and I get a requirement to instead of auto-acknowledge messages, only acknowledge them after them finish call back. I did some digging and found out there is a method called basic.ack

But I am not sure how to use it in the code. the example is using

```
channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false).
```

Where can I get the value of the deliveryTag? and where should I run the basicAck? right after my callback or inside  the callback?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

Delivery tag is available in your method object: method.delivery_tag

It is indeed not (from what I can see) present in the pika documentation, 
but the tutorials on rabbitmq.com do give the [example](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html).

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    time.sleep( body.count('.') )
    print(" [x] Done")
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
```

*sample code retrieved from the example referenced.*